# Removing the line separator but not the border in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to remove the line separator in a grouped table view cell, but not the border of the table.
I used this code to remove the separator but it removes the border also:

`profileTable.separatorColor:[UIColor clearColor];`

**The screen shot explains what I need**.

Is there any code available to remove it?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 5):

Following code may be help to you.

```
profileTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: in which method you put profileTable.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor]; this line...?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: obviously he has not a correct outlet for his tableview and that's why it's not working. disable the separator line from your NIB file instead!

Comment: You need to implement custom cell

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your problem, could be to create a custom layout for your grouped tableview. So you would create a top, middle and bottom part of the cells, and then add a border only to the sides.

I used this tutorial: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score -3):

```
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({ separatorColor: 'transparent', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' });
```

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/16584-table-view-separator-color.html

Comment: you can set  tableview's background color to the separator color